# Calling SAGA modules through GRASS run_command in a script PYTHON

Tags: python, grass-gis, saga

Does someone have an experience|example of calling modules of SAGA  with the grass.run_command method in a script written in PYTHON?

Comment: [Calling saga_cmd modules from Python](https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/wiki/Executing%20SAGA%20Modules%20with%20the%20Python%20Interface/)

Comment: Yes gene, I saw this page. It seems not possible for SAGA modules to work with the maps present the grass database. So what is the point to call them thru grass interface instead of using saga_api?

Comment: Did you install the GRASS-GDAL plugin? Then GDAL can read GRASS GIS data directly.

Comment: I don't find infos about how to use this plugin. Is it for QGIS? I have to say that my python module is out of QGIS. It works with GRASS standalone.

Comment: Here the info: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_install_GDAL-GRASS_plugin - it is to make GRASS GIS data visible from "outside" a session through GDAL/OGR.